# don't understand gcc --with-local-prefix, --with-native-system-header-dir=

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I am compiling gcc and reading manual from https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

it spcifies

> --with-local-prefix=dirname Specify the installation directory for local include files. The default is /usr/local. Specify this option if
>   you want the compiler to search directory dirname/include for locally
>   installed header files instead of /usr/local/include.

I take this to mean that when compiling other binaries with this version of GCC it will check this director before the default `/usr/.../` directoris?

> --with-sysroot=dir Tells GCC to consider dir as the root of a tree that contains (a subset of) the root filesystem of the target
>   operating system. Target system headers, libraries and run-time object
>   files will be searched for in there. More specifically, this acts as
>   if --sysroot=dir was added to the default options of the built
>   compiler.
>   If you specify the --with-native-system-header-dir=dirname option then
>   the compiler will search that directory within dirname for native
>   system headers rather than the default /usr/include.

To compile GCC 5.4.0 I `yum install gcc gcc-c++`(ie 4.8.0) and this places headers such as `stdio.h` in `/usr/include/`. After I have complied GCC 5.4.0 and specify it to complie anther binary, the 5.4.0 seems to use the 4.8.0 headers in `/usr/include/` instead of the ones created during the 5.4.0 compile.

What I am really asking is, if I want to compile GCC (5.4.0) and have the `make install` install headers as well as GCC & G++ etc in to a custom folder, what options do I set? is my configure for compiling GCC 5.4.0 correct?

```
/home/myuser/gcc-5.4.0/configure --prefix=/home/gcc540 --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-local-prefix=/home/myotherbin/local --with-gxx-include-dir=/home/gcc540/header
```

1. `--prefix=/home/gcc540` set master directory `make install`
2. `--prefix=/home/gcc540/bin` `make install` will install binaries (gcc, g++ etc)
3. `--prefix=/home/gcc540/lib` `make install` will install libs
4. `--with-gxx-include-dir=/home/gcc540/headers` `make install` will install headers for `--enable-languages=c,c++`
5. `--with-local-prefix=/home/otherprogs` (libs,headers from other dependencies are searched here first) ie this is where I would put x264 headers if I was compiling ffmpeg

so what goes in `--with-sysroot=dir`||`--with-native-system-header-dir=dirn`?

Additionally, after I have exported to `--with-gxx-include-dir=/home/gcc540/headers` I have `tr1/stdio.h` that includes the following code,

```
#include <tr1/cstdio>
```

this causes an error as both `stdio.h` and `cstdio` are in the same folder, should `stdio.h` be copied to the parent folder, or is best practice just to pass both `-I/home/gcc540/headers` -I/home/gcc540/headers/tr1` to gcc 5.4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--with-sysroot` option is only useful when you build a cross-compiler : the resulting, built gcc will know where to find the target platform's headers and libraries (i.e. it will have a default value for the --sysroot option). The `--with-native-system-header-dir` is a refinement of the `--with-sysroot` option and allows to specify a directory *relative* to the one specified for `--with-sysroot` where *native* platform headers will be found. GCC distinguishes its own headers (the ones it copies as part of `make install`) from the "native" headers that are provided by the operating system itself and were already there regardless of the GCC install.

Comment: tahnks for the detailed info on these flags. As for the last part of my question, changing the order so `/headers/tr1` comes before `/headers` solved the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can actually get gcc version 5.3.1 : "devtoolset-4" >> `yum install devtoolset-4-gcc-c++`

RHEL https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/4/html/4.1_Release_Notes/index.html

RHEL, CentOS, Fedora https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-4 ... and : packages are also available for download, 5 packages are required : {devtoolset-4-gcc-c++, -4-gcc, -4-binutils, -4-runtime, -4-libstdc++-devel}.

Please specify your OS, for more information. OS name and version, please.

---

Building gcc : gcc requires a build folder outside the source, gcc-5.4.0/ ... this will do :

```
cd build/
../gcc-5.4.0/configure --prefix=/home/gcc540 --program-suffix=54 --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib
```

No extra headers are required. It's all in /usr/ ... from the install of gcc-c++ (-4.8).

---

Comment: I need to use 5.4.0 so compiling to a non default directory is required.

Comment: Well, then go ahead. Delete all files in the build folder, and run `../configure -- ...` : I usually have no errors at all when compiling the gcc version´s 5.x.x .